# Counter example in Fenchel-Rockafellar duality: a case where the dual has no solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

With $f$ and $g$ proper convex lower semicontinuous functions, consider the primal and dual problems
$$\mathcal{S} = \arg\min_x f(x) + g(x)$$
$$\mathcal{S}^* = \arg\min_y f^*(y) + g^*(-y)$$

Fenchel-Rockafellar duality states that under the qualification condition $0 \in \mathrm{int} \, \mathrm{dom} \, f - \mathrm{dom} \, g$, $\mathcal{S}^*$ is not empty (and both infs are equal).

I'm looking for a counter example: functions $f$ and $g$ such that the dual has no solution (hence they must vioalte the QC).

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, I thought of taking $f$ and $g$ as indicator functions of the closed disks of center $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$  repsectively, both of radius 1 (they don't satisfy the QC and are an example of strict inclusion in $\partial f + \partial g \subset \partial(f + g)$). But it seems that even with these functions, the dual has a solution.

Comment: You can go the other way round: Choose $f^*$ and $g^*$ such that the dual does not have a solution and, afterwards, compute $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\ln(x)-x, &\text{if $x>0$;}\\
0, &\text{if $x=0$;}\\
+\infty, &\text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
and set $g(x) := f(-x)$.

Because $f^*(y)=\exp(y) = g^*(-y)$, the dual is to minimize $2\exp$ which has no solution.

The primal has a unique solution: $\{0\}$.